# How can I get a lookup filter for a field that points to opportunities?

Tags: opportunity, lookup-filter

Trying to put a lookup filter on a field that points to an opportunity, but the filter section does not appear when I set the related object to opportunity. I checked around and found quite a few threads saying that opportunities were not supported in lookup filters, but the link to the SF documentation below clearly states lookup filters ARE supported for opportunities. So how do I get it to appear?

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters_notes.htm&language=en_US

EDIT: I think it may have something to do with the fact that Opportunity ID is an autonumber field (whereas for accounts it is account name), and the documentation above states that lookup filters cannot reference those. Can anyone confirm this is why? It seems a bit stupid to say it is possible to put filters on fields that point to opportunities but then completely contradict that later on in the same article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it's working fine on Spring '14 but NOT on Winter '14. So seems like it should work for you after the upgrade.

That would also explain the difference in user-experiences (previous releases) and documentation (probably updated for Spring '14).

Comment: I see, thanks. I remember being told the SaaS model meant an end to everyone having different versions of the same software, guess not :/

Comment: Well the max is indeed 2 versions, since they give customers some time to test the new version before rolling it out to production. See https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/maintenance/ for the upgrade schedules.